# Transform a 2D coordinate to a 3D coordinate space

Tags: 3d, coordinate-systems, surf, coordinate-transformation

I'm working in a engine for augmented reality applications without markers (aka marketless AR) It uses interest points obtained from a SURF algorithm to identify points in any image and use those points as reference to draw the information but I don't know the best way to translate an 2D information (the interest points detected) to a 3D model to map to a 3D coordinate space and render 3D objects to the scene. Any algorithm to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question.  You should will need to do some reading in the field of Computer Vision, but briefly you would take the following approach.  You need a [fully calibrated camera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix) which describes the relationship between the camera and the world.  This model allows you to convert between points in the image and a 3D line in the world - note that you cannot get an actual 3D *point* without knowing it's depth, since a single point in the image could be the projection of many points in the world.